# Puzzle: Distributing money to a team

Tags: python, algorithm

I am working on a programming challenge where you have to distribute money to a hierarchical team. The basic idea is to figure out, for a given amount of money,
1. What is the largest number of people you can have on your team
2. What is the smallest number of people you can have on your team?

The lowest-ranked member always receives $1, and the other key rules are these:

1. A team member cannot get more than twice as much money as the member below him.

   - [1, 2, 4, 8] OK
   - [1, 2, 5, 11] INVALID
2. A team member cannot get less than the combined total of the two team members below him.

   - [1, 1, 2, 3, 5] OK
   - [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] INVALID

I thought I had this problem solved, but my program only passes 9 out of 10 test cases. Sadly, the details of the test cases are hidden from me.

So I'm trying to figure out if the flaw is in my logic or my implementation. First, the logic:

- In order to have the *largest* possible team, you should distribute the money according to the Fibonacci series i.e. [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, ... ]
- In order to end up with the *smallest* possible team, you should distribute the money according to the powers of two, i.e. [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ... ]

Do those two statements seem reasonable?

[ADDING CODE]

Sounds like they are, so now I'm trying to think what could be wrong with this code:

```
def smallest_group(total):
    pile = total
    men = 0
    while True:
        if (pile - 2 ** men) >= 0:
            pile = pile - 2 ** men
            men += 1
        else:
            # We don't have (2 ** men) money left, but
            # if we have enough money to add a team member,
            # the problem requires us to do so
            lowest = 2 ** (men-1) + 2 ** (men-2)
            if pile >= lowest:
                return men + 1
            else:
                return men

def fib():
    a,b = 1,1
    yield a
    yield b
    while True:
        a, b = b, a + b
        yield b

def largest_group(total):
    f = fib()
    pile = total
    men = 0
    for man in range(100):
        distribution = f.next()
        if (pile - distribution) >= 0:
            pile = pile - distribution
            men += 1
        else:
            return men
```

Details/Caveats:

You are not required to distribute all the money and have nothing left at the end. However, after you give one team member his distribution, if you still have enough money to add another member (obeying the conditions set forth in the problem), then you must do so.

Comment: Where is your program?

Comment: Yes, there's an inductive proof to that effect.

Comment: Suggestion: for the failing test case, check the max vals of your data types (perhaps some integral overflow) and integral<->float conversion errors. Perhaps also validate your input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the other answer is valid given your unedited question.

However given what you've stated in the comments one can assume that everything above 10 has some representation that is consistent with the constraints. Therefore your reasoning is valid with using the `2**men` and fibonacci.

Your implementation is a bit off though. These lines are a bit of a misrepresentation of what will happen to the money:

```
        # We don't have (2 ** men) money left, but
        # if we have enough money to add a team member,
        # the problem requires us to do so
        lowest = 2 ** (men-1) + 2 ** (men-2)
        if pile >= lowest:
```

The excess can just be deleted. So `men` is just returned. Therefore the following code will get the answer:

```
def smallest_group(total):
    pile = total
    men = 0
    while True:
        if (pile - 2 ** men) >= 0:
            pile = pile - 2 ** men
            men += 1
        else:
            return men

def fib():
    a,b = 1,1
    yield a
    yield b
    while True:
        a, b = b, a + b
        yield b

def largest_group(total):
    f = fib()
    pile = total
    men = 0
    for man in range(100):
        distribution = f.next()
        if (pile - distribution) >= 0:
            pile = pile - distribution
            men += 1
        else:
            return men
```

Ironically your code is more complicated than it needed to be.

Comment: In the smallest group case, you cannot distribute the money among all the employees, because you have already given each individual employee the maximum amount you are allowed to give without violating the first rule.

Comment: @wbruntra Updated the answer. I meant distributed amongst all the employees plus the one extra. Distributed didn't mean increase strictly

Comment: But the goal of the smallest_group function is to have as small a group as possible. Even though you could take away something from the second-to-last employee and give it to the the last employee, we actually prefer to not add an employee if we don't have to.

Comment: @wbruntra That's what the greater than zero condition is for. It is exactly the case "when you have to". There's something missing in your question and comments if this does not work.

Comment: To be honest, it is missing from my original question, sorry for that. However, I did comment on your earlier answer saying that we *are* allowed to end up with some money, as long as the money is not enough to pay another employee, *given the pay structure we have in place*

Comment: That can still be interpreted in multiple ways.

Comment: @wbruntra If it's what I think you're getting at then just remove the >0 condition and just return `men` if you can burn the excess money. I'll edit the answer tomorrow if you edit your question.

Comment: @wrbruntra Updated

Answer (score -1):

Changing the smallest_group function passes all the test cases:

```
def smallest_group(total):
    pile = total
    men = 0
    while True:
        if (pile - 2 ** men) >= 0:
            pile = pile - 2 ** men
            men += 1
        else:
            lowest = 2 ** (men-1) + 2 ** (men-2)
            if pile >= lowest:
                return men
                # return men + 1
            else:
                return men
```

This seems wrong to me, as I am quite certain there are at least some cases where you can add a team member even though you cannot pay him according to the 2 ** men rule. So I am not sure what to submit as my "answer" for the challenge.

Comment: What's the challenge?

Comment: It's called foo.bar, from google... basically after you make a bunch of python-related searches they will take you to a secret screen that offers this series of coding challenges. Some people say that if you do well enough it also lets you submit a resumé to google, but I don't know about that part.